# Stream and print stderr and write stout to file

Tags: python

Using python I am trying to stream stderr and print stderr to the console, while assigning the value of stdout to a variable, this code appears to do what I want, but is this how I would do this?

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["my","long","command"],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
while True: 
    line = proc.stderr.readline() 
    if not line: 
        break 
    print line 

st_out = proc.communicate()[0]
#now process st_out
```

Comment: @BhargavRao - but the code doesn't work correctly - you don't both read stdout and use communicate.

Comment: Clarificaiton - you want stderr to go to the console only and stdout to be read into a variable only (that is, stdout does not go to the console)?

Comment: Yes, stderr is being printed while stdout is read only into a variable

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the while and the if statement:

```
for line in iter(proc.stderr.readline, ""):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Popen.communicate` is used to read both stdout and stderr to completion without deadlocks. If you "pre-read" stdout, you run the risk that stderr will fill and the program will block. Since you want stderr to go to the console, you shouldn't redirect it in the first place. Just use communicate to read stdout:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["my","long","command"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
st_out = proc.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: This works when running from a shell however, I am using an ipython notebook and need stderr printed to the console as it is streaming in

Comment: I don't use ipython but I'm a bit surprised that stderr doesn't go to its console... try adding `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`. That's just a guess!